# How could i cache OCSP response with iTextSharp (LTV signature)?

Tags: caching, itext, ocsp

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.10 in order to generate signed PDF. In particular, i need LTV signature. LTV can be done with CRL and OCSP requests.

I did it with such a code :

```
IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
ICrlClient crlClient = new CrlClientOnline(myCert.Chain);
List<ICrlClient> lstCrlClients = new List<ICrlClient> { crlClient };

MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, signature, this.myCert.Chain, lstCrlClients, ocspClient, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

The problem is : i'm signing many, many PDF (always with the same certificate). So, i don't want to make CRL and OCSP request each time, i have to "cache" them.

I managed to cache the CRL with this kind of code (it relies on C# MemoryCache) :

```
private List<ICrlClient> GetCachedListCrlClient()
{
    var key = "LstCrlClient";

    List<ICrlClient> lstCrlClients = MyGlobalCachingProvider.GetItem<List<ICrlClient>>(key);
    if (lstCrlClients == null)
    {           
        lstCrlClients = new List<ICrlClient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < myCert.Chain.Length; i++)
        {
            String crlUrl = CertificateUtil.GetCRLURL(myCert.Chain[i]);
            if (crlUrl != null)
            {
                byte[] crlDownloaded = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(crlUrl);
                ICrlClient crlClient = new CrlClientOffline(crlDownloaded);
                lstCrlClients.Add(crlClient);
            }
        }
        MyGlobalCachingProvider.AddItem(key, lstCrlClients, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
    }

    return lstCrlClients;
}
```

I can't find however any solution to cache OCSP responses. Does anybody have a clue ?

Comment: OCSP responses usually have only a very short time to live. Thus, usually caching them is not worthwhile. If you are signing very many PDFs in a short time, you may want to implement a `OcspClientOffline` similar to the `CrlClientOffline`. Take a look at the code, it is trivial.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is OK. However OCSP responses aren't always short-lived : a few minutes to a few days. In my case, it's 10 days ! So i think iText should give us a standard solution for this problem...

Comment: 10 days OCSP responses? Wow! Ok, in that case I do understand that you want to cache. I'm only used to life times of not more than a few minutes.

Comment: I confirm : 10 days !! I think itextsharp should provide a solution no matter what's the OCSP lifetime. Imagine a program generating 100.000 PDF with LTV-signature (always using the same certificate). It shouldn't make 100.000 OCSP request ! A single one is enough.

Comment: You may want to provide your solution for inclusion in itext.

Comment: This is done. See below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mlk comment, i did it : i have implemented my own class, inspired by OcspClientBouncyCastle code. The code is, indeed, trivial. My class manage caching : it sends only one OCSP request. This is the good way to do the stuff.

Sample code :

```
// Once instanciated, this class fires one and only one OCSP request : it keeps the first result in memory.
// You may want to cache this object ; ie with MemoryCache.
public class MyOcspClientBouncyCastleSingleRequest : IOcspClient
{
    private static readonly ILogger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(typeof(OcspClientBouncyCastle));

    private readonly OcspVerifier verifier;

    // The request-result
    private Dictionary<String, BasicOcspResp> _cachedOcspResponse = new Dictionary<string, BasicOcspResp>();

    /**
     * Create default implemention of {@code OcspClient}.
     * Note, if you use this constructor, OCSP response will not be verified.
     */
    [Obsolete]
    public MyOcspClientBouncyCastleSingleRequest()
    {
        verifier = null;
    }

    /**
     * Create {@code OcspClient}
     * @param verifier will be used for response verification. {@see OCSPVerifier}.
     */
    public MyOcspClientBouncyCastleSingleRequest(OcspVerifier verifier)
    {
        this.verifier = verifier;
    }

    /**
     * Gets OCSP response. If {@see OCSPVerifier} was set, the response will be checked.
     */
    public virtual BasicOcspResp GetBasicOCSPResp(X509Certificate checkCert, X509Certificate rootCert, String url)
    {
        String dicKey = checkCert.SubjectDN.ToString() + "-" + rootCert.SubjectDN.ToString() + "-" + url;
        if (_cachedOcspResponse != null && _cachedOcspResponse.Count > 0 && _cachedOcspResponse.ContainsKey(dicKey))
        {
            BasicOcspResp cachedResult = _cachedOcspResponse[dicKey];
            return cachedResult;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                OcspResp ocspResponse = GetOcspResponse(checkCert, rootCert, url);
                if (ocspResponse == null)
                {
                    _cachedOcspResponse.Add(dicKey, null);
                    return null;
                }
                if (ocspResponse.Status != OcspRespStatus.Successful)
                {
                    _cachedOcspResponse.Add(dicKey, null);
                    return null;
                }
                BasicOcspResp basicResponse = (BasicOcspResp)ocspResponse.GetResponseObject();
                if (verifier != null)
                {
                    verifier.IsValidResponse(basicResponse, rootCert);
                }
                _cachedOcspResponse.Add(dicKey, basicResponse);
                return basicResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (LOGGER.IsLogging(Level.ERROR))
                    LOGGER.Error(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets an encoded byte array with OCSP validation. The method should not throw an exception.
     *
     * @param checkCert to certificate to check
     * @param rootCert  the parent certificate
     * @param url       to get the verification. It it's null it will be taken
     *                  from the check cert or from other implementation specific source
     * @return a byte array with the validation or null if the validation could not be obtained
     */
    public byte[] GetEncoded(X509Certificate checkCert, X509Certificate rootCert, String url)
    {
        try
        {
            BasicOcspResp basicResponse = GetBasicOCSPResp(checkCert, rootCert, url);
            if (basicResponse != null)
            {
                SingleResp[] responses = basicResponse.Responses;
                if (responses.Length == 1)
                {
                    SingleResp resp = responses[0];
                    Object status = resp.GetCertStatus();
                    if (status == CertificateStatus.Good)
                    {
                        return basicResponse.GetEncoded();
                    }
                    else if (status is RevokedStatus)
                    {
                        throw new IOException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("ocsp.status.is.revoked"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new IOException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("ocsp.status.is.unknown"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (LOGGER.IsLogging(Level.ERROR))
                LOGGER.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
    * Generates an OCSP request using BouncyCastle.
    * @param issuerCert certificate of the issues
    * @param serialNumber   serial number
    * @return   an OCSP request
    * @throws OCSPException
    * @throws IOException
    */
    private static OcspReq GenerateOCSPRequest(X509Certificate issuerCert, BigInteger serialNumber)
    {
        // Generate the id for the certificate we are looking for
        CertificateID id = new CertificateID(CertificateID.HashSha1, issuerCert, serialNumber);

        // basic request generation with nonce
        OcspReqGenerator gen = new OcspReqGenerator();
        gen.AddRequest(id);

        // create details for nonce extension
        IDictionary extensions = new Hashtable();

        extensions[OcspObjectIdentifiers.PkixOcspNonce] = new X509Extension(false, new DerOctetString(new DerOctetString(PdfEncryption.CreateDocumentId()).GetEncoded()));

        gen.SetRequestExtensions(new X509Extensions(extensions));
        return gen.Generate();
    }

    private OcspResp GetOcspResponse(X509Certificate checkCert, X509Certificate rootCert, String url)
    {
        if (checkCert == null || rootCert == null)
            return null;
        if (url == null)
        {
            url = CertificateUtil.GetOCSPURL(checkCert);
        }
        if (url == null)
            return null;
        LOGGER.Info("Getting OCSP from " + url);
        OcspReq request = GenerateOCSPRequest(rootCert, checkCert.SerialNumber);
        byte[] array = request.GetEncoded();

        HttpWebRequest con = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        con.ContentLength = array.Length;
        con.ContentType = "application/ocsp-request";
        con.Accept = "application/ocsp-response";
        con.Method = "POST";
        Stream outp = con.GetRequestStream();
        outp.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        outp.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)con.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new IOException(MessageLocalization.GetComposedMessage("invalid.http.response.1", (int)response.StatusCode));
        Stream inp = response.GetResponseStream();
        OcspResp ocspResponse = new OcspResp(inp);
        inp.Close();
        response.Close();
        return ocspResponse;
    }
```